# Having trouble trying to deploy my Angular app to Netlify

Tags: angular, deployment, frontend, netlify

I made my first app with Angular, basically it's just a frontend app. I'm trying to deploy it using Netlify. I did it 2 ways: Manually in the Netlify website, connecting it to my app repo on Github. It did not work... I tried a second time with netlify deploy on my visual studio code and everything generated perfectly, but still i got the same error when I open my app... And I noticed something else. My Netlify isn't detecting my dist carpet, but it exist in my project as u can see below (and the successful deployment in the vs console)

[image]

The error I get everytime I open my site is this one:

[image]

This my site config on Netlify:

[image]

This is the error I just saw on the Netlifly in regards to my dist carpet... And other errors that I don't get because it was succesful in my vs console...

[image]

This is my git repository where u can check my app and code:

https://github.com/AndreaAldana/AppDeTareas

I don't know what I did wrong. I did some research and I saw some things about not having my index.html in my dist, but I just check my carpet and I have it! The thing is my Netlify app doesn't recognize the dist carpet. Can someone help me? I've never used netlify and I followed some guides but it ends with the same result...

Comment: What do your Netlify build settings look like? To run Angular from GitHub in Netlify, you need to set up build settings/options to have the Build command: `ng build --prod` and you need a publish directory set to `dist/projectname`

Comment: Excuse my ignorance I've never used Netlify. I did use ng build and it generated the dist carpet on my project, but I don't know how to point netlify to this folder...

Comment: :O I will try it that way. How can I create a public directory? That means I don't need to use the dist carpet?

Comment: Repository = github.com/AndreaAldana/AppDeTareas,
Base directory = Not set,
Build command = ng build --prod,
Publish directory = dist\ListTareas,
Deploy log visibility= Logs are public,
Builds Active

Comment: Thats my build, I just added the Build command but it still doesn't work. Should I try to deploy it again?

Comment: Deploy it again and show the log here if it fails. The new settings should work.